# How do i set a velocity of a KINEMATIC body in pymunk?

Tags: python, pymunk

Im trying to set the velocity of a KINEMATIC body in pymunk but i dont really know what does what or what values do i need to put, if anyone can explain it to me ill be greatfull.

here is what i did -

```
part_body = pymunk.Body(1, 1666, pymunk.Body.KINEMATIC)
part_shape = pymunk.Segment(part_body, (0, 150), (300, 150), 2)
part_shape.body.position = 0, 0      # Set the position of the body
part_shape.body.velocity = (0, 0)
```

i have no idea why i need to put a tuple and not an int, and what the tuple does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The velocity has a direction. Some examples:

if you set it to `(1,0)` it means move to the right with a velocity of 1, after 1 unit of time the object will be at position `(1,0)`.

If you set it to `(10,0)` it also means move to the right, but with a velocity of 10, so end up at position `(10,0)` after 1 unit of time.

If you set it to `(10,10)` it will move to the right-up with a velocity of about 14 (`sqrt(10**2 + 10**2)`), so will en up at position `(10,10)` after 1 unit of time.

Comment: Thank you for explaining me that :)